# ViewPager delete a page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I permanently delete a page from a view pager. I want to delete a page when the user presses a button present on that screen. I am struggling a lot with this. I read the documentation of pageradapter and  found the destroyitem but it didn't help me much though. I am able to add the images in viewpager but deleting is still giving me a tough time. Please help.

Below is the code for the activity in which images are fetched and I want to delete an image on user request.

```
public class ImageDisplayActivity extends Activity {
private List<String> filePaths;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display1);


    // Get Image Paths for the PagerAdapter
    filePaths = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("filePaths");
    int currPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currPosition);

    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = ImageDisplayActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        int padding = 16;
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        // Get Image
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePaths.get(position), bmOptions);

        // Display Image
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object imageView) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) imageView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: remove it from your adapter not from the viewpager

Comment: can you be more specific please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kuffs is saying, remove the items from filePaths, then notify the adapter about that the underlying data has changed:

```
filePaths.remove(...); // Remove whatever you want
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); // Tell the adapter that it's time to update views
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer because I cannot comment.

You can try removing it from the adapter. Add this to your destroyItem:

```
if(position == conditionToRemove){
    filePaths.remove(position); 
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

And, you'll have to make ImagePagerAdapter a global variable.
Hope this helps!

Comment: okay, i did not realise someone has posted an answer! should I delete this or leave it?

Comment: sure.. under what condition would you want to delete the page?

Comment: I am placing a button at the bottom of each page, on click of that

Comment: You'll have to create an xml file with an image view and a button and inflate that view

Comment: where do you inflate it?